# Params is nil or empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi I am new to Ruby on Rails.I have html select and label elements in my view.

But when I try to get their values by params[:select_id] it returns nil.So the html elements are not present in the params hash.Here is the code of
my view page:

```
 <%=form_tag do %>
    <select id="selectmarka" name="lists">
    <% @MarkaAdi.each do |m| %>
    <option value="<%=m.MarkaAdi %>"><%=m.MarkaAdi %></option>
    <%end%>
    </select>

    <% @TipAdi=List.where("MarkaAdi='"+session[:key] +"'")%>

      <select id="selecttip" name="lists">
    <% @TipAdi.each do |t| %>
    <option value="<%=t.TipAdi %>"><%=t.TipAdi %></option>
    <%end%>
    </select> 

    <%=session[:key]%>
    <input type="hidden" id="hid" name="hid" value="<%=session[:key] %>" />

    <select id="year" name="lists">
    <%(1999..2013).each do |i| %>
    <option value="Y"+"<%=i%>"><%=i%></option>
    <%end%>
    </select>

    <br>Deger:<label id="deger" name="deger"><%=@result%></label>
    <br>Marka Kodu:<label id="markakodu" name="markakodu"></label>
    <br>Tip Kodu:<label id="tipkodu" name="tipkodu"></label>

    <%end%>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any HTML elements whose name is 'select_id'.  You have three that are named 'lists' (probably not what you want) and a hidden field named 'hid'.

Look at your development.log which will show you what is being passed in the params hash.

Comment: 'select_id' was just for example.I write params[:selectmarka] or params[:selecttip].They both return empty.So I can't access the form elements' values

Comment: @user2192847  You don't have any inputs whose name attribute is :selectmarka or :selecttip.  They are all named "lists".  Yes, you've set the id attribute, but that isn't what gets POSTed.

Comment: I have tried setting the name as "selectmarka" <select id="selectmarka" name="selectmarka">.....</select> but still params[:selectmarka] returns empty

Comment: Thank you all for your help.I have solved it.I just forgot to give the form an action,a method and a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to create HTML inputs using the Rails form helpers

```
<%= form_tag do %>

  <%= text_field_tag :an_input, 'a default value' %>
  <%= text_area_tag :a_textarea, 'a default value' %>
  <%= select_tag options_for_select([ ['value', 'key'], [...] ]) %>

  <%= submit_tag %>

<% end %>
```

This way, Rails will generate the proper params for you by conventions base on how you named your inputs. You may want to read this well written guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Also, as convention, writing ruby code should be done in "snake_case" so `@MarkaAdi` should be `@marka_adi`

Comment: I have pasted the code but when I write "params.inspect" it says:{"action"=>"page1", "controller"=>"lists"}.And I tried params[:an_input] but it returns empty.I dont know why the elements arent added to params hash